# How to register a unity IoC type in web.config so that it uses a specific constructor?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-config, config, unity-container

I've found several places that explain how to specify a constructor when registering a type in Unity IoC using source code, but what about in a configuration file? I'd like to register a type in my web.config and specify which constructor to be used, however I don't want to pass the parameter in the config file, I need to pass the parameter in code during a resolve. Is this possible?

Appreciate your time and assistance on this!

Answer (score 0):

I found it, at least this is working for me. To specify a constructor when registering in web.config I added the param element without a value and specified the param was a dependency. See example below:

```
<constructor>
   <param name="connectionString">
      <dependency />
   </param>
</constructor>
```

I then passed the dependency in code using:

```
container.Resolve(Of MyObject)(New ParameterOverride("connectionString", "Real connection String value"))
```